# Number of possible value for $\tan \{x\} = 1$.

Tags: functions, trigonometry

The number of solution of equation $\sin \{x\} = \cos \{x\}$ in the interval $[-2\pi,2\pi]$ is, where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$.

My thoughts: Dividing both sides by $\cos\{x\}$ we get $\tan\{x\}=1$. I know the general solution for $\tan x=1$ but, what about $\tan\{x\}$? Please help me on this. Some hints would also do. (I know what fractional part function is all about)

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan%7Bfrac%28x%29%7D%3D1

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\tan y = 1$ and $0\le y<1$ imply $y=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

$sin(x)$ & $cos(x)$ intersects each other in the interval $[0, 1]$ only once.

[image: sinusoid]

And for $sin\{x\} \&\ cos\{x\}$ the portion of the above graph between $[0, 1)$ will be repeated for every interval $[n, n+1)\ \forall n\in \mathbb{Z}$. So for every such interval we've $1$ solution point (i.e $n+\frac{\pi}{4}$). Between $[-2\pi, 2\pi]$ there are $12$ such points where $sin\{x\}\ \&\ cos\{x\}$ intersects.

So our solution is $12$.